# Should I install Ubuntu on and old HP laptop (HP 250 G3)?

Tags: laptop, hp

due to the situation regarding covid, school will be online for who knows how long. Now, in my family there are not enough computers for everyone to use at the same time. I've found an old HP 250 G3 ( 2 GB of working memory, a 500 GB hard drive and an Intel Celeron N2830 2.16ghz) laptop laying around I thought was broken. It has windows 10 installed but it works very slow and the windows is bloated with programs/apps no one uses. Due to financial reasons it would be optimal if the old HP could be somehow revived with Ubuntu :). Now my questions are:

- can linux be sufficient for light school work for children aged 7-10?
- can I run Microsoft Teams on ubuntu? is it stable?
- which version/flavour of Ubuntu would be optimal?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read and answer my questions!

Comment: For that pc I suggest MX Linux, MS Teams will run smoothly. https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/files/Final/MX-19.2_386.iso/download

Comment: Lubuntu will probably be best for your ram amount.  Will want 18.04 or 20.04.  Quite a few education type programs for linux, google for a decent list.  Link for teams.  https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-microsoft-teams-linux-on-ubuntu-and-centos/

Comment: Just check your CPU, it is a baytrail model and might have a random freeze problem.  There is a fix for it if you find it freezing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your given system requirement, **Lubuntu** would be best suited

Minimum hardware requirements for Lubuntu:

**RAM: 1 GB of RAM**

**CPU: Pentium 4 or Pentium M or AMD K8 or higher**

Talking of Microsoft Teams, it is not necessary to install Teams as an App by default. I myself been using Teams daily on Browser. You could Sign In through this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software

Moreover Microsoft Teams is more stable, updated and faster in Browser Version compared to Desktop App.

My recommended browser would be **Vivaldi** over Firefox as it is the Fastest Web Browser

Answer (score 0):

I have an old HP Pavillion - perhaps slightly more powerful as it at least has a Pentium chip, but it was as slow as an old arthritic dog with Windows 10 so I decided Linux was the way to go as opposed to selling it for next to nothing.

MX was my first choice but I just couldn't get on with it. Way too ugly (although I know you can improve it) and after using Ubuntu 18.04 for ages it just felt alien.

In the end I went for Lubuntu. It runs adequately quickly - so PC is fine for basic tasks. While I prefer it to MX, it does feel very dated compared to Ubuntu, but hey, anything's better than Windows!

Good luck.